# How to include the Smart Search box in my home page?

Tags: joomla-3.x, search, smartsearch

Currently I am having the normal search box in my home page with,

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="search" style="xhtml" />
```

I want to replace it with Smart Search plugin as I need to change some indexing in it. Current search listing all the results but I want to unindex some categories from search. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

The tag:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="search" style="xhtml" />
```

sets up a module position in your template called 'search'. If you look at your module list you will find a search module set to that position.  Unpublish that module and make a new module of the type 'smart search' and set its position to 'search'.

Often it's also a good idea to make a menu item for the smart search results too.